# How do I show all grants to all roles in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, I know I can show roles:

```
show roles
```

I know I can show grants on specific roles and access those via query:

```
show grants to role dev_role;
select * from table(RESULT_SCAN (LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

I'd like to show ALL grants for ALL roles in one table. My best guess would be to write a procedure that iterates through all the role names, executes the above code, and outputs the result to a table.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have access to the shared database called [snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage.html#what-is-the-snowflake-database)? If not then you may need to ask an `accountadmin` to provide you the `IMPORTED PRIVILEGES` grant as explained [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage.html#enabling-account-usage-for-other-roles).

Anyway if you have access to this database then I think you should be able to get the info you need from the [GRANTS_TO_ROLES](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/grants_to_roles.html) view:

```sql
select * 
from snowflake.account_usage.grants_to_roles;
```

Comment: Note: This will not include future grants. Remember to show future grants to get a complete picture of grants: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/show-grants.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not currently a better way to accumulate the grant information.  My current solution is exactly what you've described.